# Why does NSDictionary sometimes remove quotes when using dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, quotes

I have the following line of code...

```
NSDictionary *visitDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.room.roomId, @"room_id", self.datePicker.date, @"date", nil];
```

which outputs this result...

```
Dict: {
    date = "2014-05-05 22:15:02 +0000";
    "room_id" = 12;
}
```

room_id has quotes around it, but date does not.

If I called it date_a it will have quotes around it. But date does not. I can't escape the first line of code to be

```
NSDictionary *visitDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.room.roomId, @"room_id", self.datePicker.date, @"\"date\"", nil];
```

either because then I just end up with this.

```
Dict: {
    "\"date\"" = "2014-05-05 22:18:33 +0000";
    "room_id" = 6;
}
```

What gives? I need quotes around this key, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

In the 1st line of code you posted, none of the values actually have any quotes in them.

When you log an `NSDictionary`, values only appear in quotes if the key/value has spaces, underscores, or other special punctuation.

In your 2nd line of code you posted, your "date" key actually has quotes in the key value.

When you log that dictionary, those quotes are shown along with a backslash (though the backslash isn't actually in the string) and since the value has some special characters, it is shown in quotes.

To clarify, `NSDictionary` never removes anything.

Comment: Ok, so if I go to post this comment to a rails back end that expects the quotes, that will all be taken care of?

Comment: What comment? Now you are asking a completely separate question that has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Even I am encountering the same issue,i also need the parameter with quotes in order to get the correct response from the server.Any idea